# remove white-space in isotope js

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-isotope

There is space in-between each item in my grid. http://okbj.ca/ If you click on most recent or resize the window it will remove the space. When you refresh the space comes back. How can I remove this space for good?

I am using the latest versions of chrome, explorer, microsoft edge and firefox. It seems to not work on all of them.

[image]

Comment: Please include a screenshot in your question of what you're seeing and what browser you're seeing it in.

Comment: I have provided a link to my website. http://okbj.ca/ I will also upload a screen shot now

Comment: Your website may not always be around or look the same way. In order to make sure this question stays relevant, provide as much context in the question as possible.

Comment: Please add the image directly to the question. There is no need to use imgur. Also, edit the question to add more information about what browser you're using.

Comment: My account is limited to only providing a link

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a browser-specific issue for you because it appears fine in the latest version of Chrome, Firefox and Safari on OSX.

[image]

It appears the issue occurs on Windows. There are two solutions.

**Ugly Javascript Hack**

Fire a resize event every second. This will force the plugin to recalculate the sizes.

```
// cross-browser resize event
var crossBrowserResize = function() {
    var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    evt.initEvent('resize', true, false);
    window.dispatchEvent(evt);
};

// fire the event every second
setInterval(function() {
    crossBrowserResize();
}, 1000);
```

**Use Media Queries Instead**

This type of grid is easily achievable using pure CSS and some media queries. I inspected the elements and they're already using several media queries to adjust how things resize at different breakpoints.

```
/* 4 columns on tablet landscape and up */
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .block {
    width: 25%;
  }
}

/* 2 columns on tablet profile */
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .block {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

/* 1 column on phone landscape or profile */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .block {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: it does not. I have the latest update to chrome and no it shows. it also shows on explorer

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer? Please update your question with as much detail as possible.

Comment: I am using the latest versions of chrome, explorer, microsoft edge and firefox. It seems to not work on all of them.and even if it is not working in the older versions i still need a fix.

Comment: I created those media queries. How does using media quires help removing the spaces though?

Comment: Because now you're not relying on the plugin for layout so it won't miscalculate. It'll always be 4, 2, or 1 columns depending on the width.

Answer (score 0):

The collapse you want happens only on window resize event (in Chrome). You can dispatch the event once the grid is loaded:

```
(function fixGrid() {
  var img, grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
  if (grid) {img = grid.querySelector('img');}
  if (img && img.height) {
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
    grid.style.opacity = 1;
  } else {
    if (grid) {grid.style.opacity = 0;}
    setTimeout(fixGrid, 10);
  }
})();
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. Thanks for help though

Comment: I edited the answer with a more "agressive" approach. This self executed function can be added in a &lt;script> tag in the HTML code,  to ensure it's executed. I'll test it later on with the browser console in you site.

Comment: it works but unfortunately not before loading everything. So you can see the adjustment... Is there a way to do it so the adjustment is hidden? Without me adding a loading screen or something. Thanks You!

Comment: You could set `visibility: hidden` until that timeout fires.

Comment: Updated with opacity change, but I can't test it remotely since this happens in the loading stage.